# Querio crear una matriz en java dependiendo de si un valor es mayor que otro pero me salta un error

Tags: java, matriz

Hice el siguiente fragmento de codigo pero me dice que en los casos del `if` los `;` estan "expected", en el problema se me ingrean varias filas como array, "datosFila" es el largo de la fila mas larga y "fila" es la cantidad de filas que ingresan

```
    int mat[][] = new int[fila][fila];
            if (datosFila > fila) {
                mat[][] = new int [datosFila][datosFila];
            } else {
                mat[][] = new int [fila][fila];
            }
```

Comment: una vez declarado los tamaños del array bidimensional ,estos valores no pueden cambiarse,deberas crear un array bidimensional para tu primera condicional y un segundo array  para else

Comment: if (datosFila > fila) {
            int mat[][] = new int[datosFila][datosFila];
        } else {
            int mat[][] = new int[fila][fila];
        }
/*Algo asi?  porque probe haciendo esto pero no me deja acceder al array luego en un for*/

Comment: Seria asi `if (datosFila > fila) { int mat2[][] = new int[datosFila][datosFila]; } else { int mat2[][] = new int[fila][fila]; }` recuerda que el array bidimensional `mat` ya esta declarado

Comment: Claro ahi me soluciono el problema del expected pero no me deja usar la array mat2 para este for " for (int i = 0; i < mat2.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mat2[0].length; j++) {
                    if (mat2[i][j] == 0) {
                        mat2[i][j] = max;
                    }"

Comment: Las variables solo están disponibles en su `scope`, si la declaras dentro de un bloque de código, no está disponible fuera del mismo. Prueba a declarar la matriz primero: `int mat[][];` y luego en el if simplemente la asignas tal como estás haciendo, simplemente no la instancies (darle valor) al declararla.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los valores del nuevo array generado en base a la condicional `if` o `else`, puedes declarar `mat2` como variable global

Ejemplo basado en la descripción de tu cuestión

```
int[][]mat=new int[fila][colum];
//creas una instancia de una matriz bidimensional llamada mat2
int[][]mat2=null;

//segun las condicional mat 2 tomara los respectivos valores
if(fila>colum){
 mat2=new int[fila][fila];

}else{
 mat2=new int[colum][colum];
}

int max=9;

///luego de ello podes usar mat2 para lo que requieras
for (int i = 0; i < mat2.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<mat2[i].length;j++ ) {
    if (mat2[i][j] == 0) { 
        mat2[i][j] = max;
      }
}
}
```